# configure SourceMapDevToolPlugin to generate "source-map"

Tags: javascript, webpack-4

TL;DR

What config options do I need to set in the SourceMapDevToolPlugin to emulate `devtool: 'source-map'`?

I *have* to use `SourceMapDevToolPlugin` to avoid generating a source map for my vendor modules....but I want `source-map` style maps, not `inline-source-map`.

Details:

I'm using webpack 4, and don't want to waste time generating a `vendor.js.map`, so I can't just set `devtool` and I instead do this:

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/source-map-dev-tool-plugin/#exclude-vendor-maps

but I notice this comment:

> You can use the following code to replace the configuration option devtool: inline-source-map with an equivalent custom plugin configuration:

I, for the life of me, can't figure out what options I need to pass in to the plugin to replicate `devtool: 'source-map'`, instead of `inline-source-map`

my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "webpack -p --config webpack.prod.js",
   "start": "webpack-dev-server --debug --bail --config webpack.dev.js"
},
```

my (relavent) webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
   devtool: false, // using SourceMapDevToolPlugin instead
   optimization: {
     splitChunks: {
       cacheGroups: {
         commons: {
           test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
           name: 'vendors',
           chunks: 'all'
         },
         styles: {
           test: /\.css$/,
           name: 'styles',
           chunks: 'all'
         }
      }
   },
   plugins: [
     new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
       filename: '[name].map',
       exclude: ['vendor.js']
     })
   ]
}
```

and my dev config:

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './public',
    stats: 'minimal'
  }
});
```

and my prod config

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  stats: 'errors-only'
});
```

Answer (score 7):

From the docs, emphasis mine:

`filename` (`string`): Defines the output filename of the SourceMap (will be ***inlined if no value is provided***).

which means that if you specify the `filename` option you have identical behavior to `devtool: 'source-map'`

`devtool: 'inline-source-map'` === `new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({})`

`devtool: 'source-map'` === `new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({ filename: '[file].map' })`

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same question trying to exclude a part of the code from source map. Since I could not get answers to my satisfaction in the Internet, I looked at the source codes of Webpack, and found the following code used by Webpack

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js

```
if (
            options.devtool &&
            (options.devtool.includes("sourcemap") ||
                options.devtool.includes("source-map"))
        ) {
            const hidden = options.devtool.includes("hidden");
            const inline = options.devtool.includes("inline");
            const evalWrapped = options.devtool.includes("eval");
            const cheap = options.devtool.includes("cheap");
            const moduleMaps = options.devtool.includes("module");
            noSources = options.devtool.includes("nosources");
            legacy = options.devtool.includes("@");
            modern = options.devtool.includes("#");
            comment =
                legacy && modern
                    ? "\n/*\n//@ source" +
                      "MappingURL=[url]\n//# source" +
                      "MappingURL=[url]\n*/"
                    : legacy
                    ? "\n/*\n//@ source" + "MappingURL=[url]\n*/"
                    : modern
                    ? "\n//# source" + "MappingURL=[url]"
                    : null;
            const Plugin = evalWrapped
                ? EvalSourceMapDevToolPlugin
                : SourceMapDevToolPlugin;
            new Plugin({
                filename: inline ? null : options.output.sourceMapFilename,
                moduleFilenameTemplate: options.output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate,
                fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate:
                    options.output.devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate,
                append: hidden ? false : comment,
                module: moduleMaps ? true : cheap ? false : true,
                columns: cheap ? false : true,
                lineToLine: options.output.devtoolLineToLine,
                noSources: noSources,
                namespace: options.output.devtoolNamespace
            }).apply(compiler);
        }
```

So you can see, the options for the SourceMapDevToolPlugin could depend on some of your output webpack configurations (sourceMapFilename, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate, devtoolLineToLine, devtoolNamespace - see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output).

For my webpack config, the final options that were going in to SourceMapDevToolPlugin when I used devtool: 'source-map' were as follows:

```
{
    "filename": "[file].map[query]",
    "append": null,
    "module": true,
    "columns": true,
    "lineToLine": false,
    "noSources": false,
    "namespace": ""
}
```

If you are not using any of the mentioned output options then the above should be fine for you.  Otherwise, you will need to take them into consideration. You can modify the node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js to add a console.log with JSON.stringify() to see what exact parameters were used for your Webpack configuration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "You can modify the node_modules/webpack/lib/WebpackOptionsApply.js to add a console.log with JSON.stringify()" - slick